# check if compilation has indeed finished?

Tags: linux, opencv, compilation, cmake

I was compiling opencv from source using `cmake` in Raspberry Pi. The guide that I was following says that it took him 10 hours. So I left it overnight. But when I woke up, my windows restarted due to some unexpected error, so is my ssh to Pi!

I tried running `ps` in Pi to check if it's still compiling but it just list `bash` and `ps`. Is there way for me to check whether my raspberry pi (that runs in linux) is still compiling or has finished successfully or finished with errors?

(P.s. when pc got restarted, pi is still on)

FOLLOW UP QUESTIONS:

How do I know the compilation progress of CMake? Is there a log for it?

If `.so` files were actually present in the lib folder, does those `.so` produced guarantee itself that it has been produced successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regular `ps` only gives you processes associated with the current terminal. Use `ps -eF` or `ps aux` to get all of the processes.

Running `make` is a good way to check, if it returns immediately saying that there's nothing to do, then it has finished with the compilation.

Comment: If the pi is still compiling, would I see under CMD the name "make"? Since I invoke the command make to start compilation last night.

Answer (score 0):

I run make install since .so are already present in the lib folder. CMake was smart enough to detect compiled libraries and so it resumed the compilation at 58% :)

Comment: yes, make has a depedency system, if some depenedencies have not been changed, they will not be recompiled.